# PrettyPhoto/jQuery load from click

Tags: jquery, prettyphoto

I'm a bit new to jQuery and I'm trying to do something that I would think is straightforward, but I cannot seem to crack it.

I want to create a function that loads different videos when you click on a button. All of the samples for PrettyPhoto that I have seen are using tags in the html, not JS click.

To summarize my code, I have something along the lines of:

```
$("#button1").click(function() {
  openMovie("myMovie.mp4");
}); 


function openMovie(url) {
  //open up the movie at the url passed into the function as a lightbox with PrettyPhoto    
}
```

I would think this would be simple, but I can't seem to find any info on how to do it. The documentation is all inline html

I was able to find some code online for images that I altered, but it throws an error:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
$.prettyPhoto.open(['assets/myMovie.mp4'],['Test']);
```

**

> Image cannot be loaded. Make sure the path is correct and image exist.

**

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to be able to support IE6/7/8? It's fairly simple with HTMl5 + jQuery, but I won't go to the effort until I know what you need to support. Also what structure of loading do you want? Random video, or pull a specific URL?

Comment: Actually, this is being built specifically for the iPad on an internal site so I don't have to worry about anything except Safari.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get this working by changing the code:

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
```

to

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto[movies]']").prettyPhoto();
```